# Как добавить на яндекс.карту маркеры c данными из БД в Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

Всем привет, я делаю проект на laravel и мне нужно добавить на яндекс.карту маркеры компаний из БД. Подскажите,пожалуйста, как лучше сделать.Буду рад любой помощи.

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [53.902512, 27.561481],
            zoom: 7
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
    
        myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([53.902512, 27.561481], {
            hintContent: ''
        }, {
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            iconImageHref: 'img/map_marker.png',
            iconImageSize: [27, 33],
            iconImageOffset: [27, -28]
        });
    
        myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([55.183672, 30.204791], {
            hintContent: ''
        }, {
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            iconImageHref: 'img/map_marker.png',
            iconImageSize: [27, 33],
             iconImageOffset: [27, -28]
        });        
    
        myPlacemark3 = new ymaps.Placemark([54.510741, 30.429586], {
            hintContent: ''
        }, {
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            iconImageHref: 'img/map_marker.png',
            iconImageSize: [27, 33],
             iconImageOffset: [27, -28]
        });
     myMap.geoObjects
        .add(myPlacemark1)
        .add(myPlacemark2)
        .add(myPlacemark3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант получить из базы адреса ваших компаний. Затем по каждому адресу получить координаты, используя геокодер Яндекса. Он возвращает координаты . Вот их и нанести на карту.
Однако запросы в геокодер платные, свыше выделенного лимита.
Все это описано в документации к API Yandex Maps.